# UnboundLocalError with recursive URI call using requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, python-requests

I have this bit of code that, well, fetches a page from the given url.

In the try/except clause, if an exception occurs, the program sleeps for a couple of second, prints the traceback, and then recursively starts again.

```
def fetch_page(self, url):
    head = {'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"}
    time.sleep(2)
    print "..."
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'error', url, "Trying again"
        traceback.print_exc()
        self.fetch_page(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print r.status_code
    return r.text
```

But whenever an exception occurs, the code succesfully sleeps, makes a recursive call, prints `r.status_code`, and then gives a `UnboundLocalError` on `r.raise_for_status()`.

```
...
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./calling.py", line 140, in <module>
    get_valid_url = Get()
  File "./calling.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.call()
  File "./calling.py", line 44, in call
    text = self.fetch_page(link.strip('\n'))
  File "./calling.py", line 35, in fetch_page
    r.raise_for_status()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

Now, if `r` was referenced before assignment, why is it printing `r.status_code`?

My first guess was maybe I messed up the recursive call. But that doesn't makes any sense. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you run your function and get a 404 the first time. You enter the `except` block, and recursively call `fetch_page` again. Say you get a 200 this time. You don't enter the `except` block; instead, you run to the end of the function and `return r.text`.

Control then returns to the caller, which is your previous invocation of `fetch_page`. The next line of code, which is `r.raise_for_status()`, is executed. But in *this* invocation of `fetch_page` (the top-level one), `r` was never actually defined, because an exception was thrown in the `try` block. Hence, an `UnboundLocalError`.

One possible resolution - instead of this:

```
except:
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'error', url, "Trying again"
    traceback.print_exc()
    self.fetch_page(url)
```

Return the result of the recursive call to `fetch_page`:

```
except:
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'error', url, "Trying again"
    traceback.print_exc()
    return self.fetch_page(url)
```

I would also suggest maybe doing something more like this, so you don't have returns at different indent levels when you can avoid it:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print r.status_code
    return r.text
except:
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'error', url, "Trying again"
    traceback.print_exc()
    return self.fetch_page(url)
```